# How to Create Account with a new user using Google Sign In?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have successfully implemented the Google Sign in itself with the Firebase SDK, but I am at a block where a new account is not being created if it doesn't exist already.

```
extension AuthViewModel {        
    func signInWithGoogle() async -> Bool {
        guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else {
            print("NO ACCOUNT")
            fatalError("NO CLIENT ID FOUND IN FIREBASE CONFIG")
        }
        let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.configuration = config            
        
        guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
              let window = windowScene.windows.first,
              let rootViewController = window.rootViewController else {
            print("There is no root view controller")
            return false
        }
        
        do {
            let userAuthentication = try await GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: rootViewController)
            let user = userAuthentication.user
            guard let idToken = user.idToken else {
                throw AuthenticationError.tokenError(message: "ID TOKEN NOT AVAILABLE")
            }
            let accessToken = user.accessToken
            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken.tokenString, accessToken: accessToken.tokenString)
            let result = try await Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)
            self.userSession = result.user
            await fetchUser()
            return true
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }            
        // return false        
    }
}
```

A new Google account is registered with Firebase Authentication, but a new account within the app is not created for the user. After the log in, the app goes to a completely blank page, and stays on this page, even if the application is rebuilt and deleted from the iPhone simulator.

Does this have to do anything with the implementation of the GIDConfiguration model?

This is my account creation code for someone that uses their email address and password to sign in.

```
func createUser (withEmail email: String, password: String, fullname: String) async throws{
    do {
        let result = try await Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
        self.userSession = result.user
        let user = User(id: result.user.uid, fullname: fullname, email: email)
        let encodedUser = try Firestore.Encoder().encode(user)
        try await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.id).setData(encodedUser)
        await fetchUser()
    } catch  {
        print("Dbug, failed to create user with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        
    }
}
```

I also Deleted the registered Google account from the Firebase Authentication to reset the app, but that app is still stuck on a blank screen.